# Keep Compose UI test waiting without freezing thread

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, gui-testing

Is this possible during test to wait N amount of time, without freezing main thread. I am testing Compose app, and not sure how to do it.
For now I use :

> Thread.sleep(timeoutMs:Long)

But app just freeze and incoming data not displayed, since it Compose for Wear Os, so I can't verify how display values change.
Is there a way to perform some sort of delay in such case ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What is the final goal of waiting?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti main idea to gather data from heart rate, wait few minutes, collect data and pass it to next screen. For use on emulators, i wrote custom heart sensor that generates fake "heart beat values", I wanted to read generated values and then compare it to values in statistic (like average, min, best, max e.t.c)

Comment: If the sensor is mocked, why should you wait?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand this fully, but I think you should look more into kotlin coroutines and flows.

Coroutines can achieve the effect you seek, and are bound really well to compose as internal support.

I cannot answer your question fully because you didn't show any snippet of code to work on, but with coroutines and flows you can create a flow, wait any amount of seconds and emit a value into the flows once the waiting is done.

Flows can be listened to in Compose by using the `collectAsState` method.